# How to get more stamina by running

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Do I need to sprint (i.e. tap the run button) in order to train up my stamina? Or is just plain running by holding the button down enough?

And if the latter, does sprinting increase the stat faster?

Comment: Biking and swimming are good too! :3

Comment: @Fluttershy Didn't know those were a thing! What *isn't* in this game? o.O

Comment: @AnnaLear Monkeys on motorcycles shooting people....wait, that's in a preview before Meltdown the movie... yeah this game does have everything.

Comment: @AnnaLear Gambling?

Comment: if your motivation to ask this question is laziness, you can also increase your stamina with *blackjack and hookers*. Well, maybe not blackjack, but hookers do increase your stamina. I don't know how fast, but I recently got 100% for Michael while I was in the car with a woman. For your question: I'd guess that just holding the button is not enough, because in triathlon you can run/swim/cycle by just holding the button and your *remaining stamina* will be slowly regenerating. But that's just a guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase your stamina by sprinting (tapping the run button) as I learned from experience yesterday. When you do the first bicycle mission you also get a tooltip that says something to the tune of "biking helps increase your stamina", after which you also go for a swim, during which I increased my skill yet again by tapping the run button while swimming.

So, in summary:

- Tap run button while running
- Tap run button while swimming
- Tap run button while biking

Comment: This seems consistent with the, uh, research I finally did last night. Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: But the question was do you gain stamina without tapping X but by simply holding it to jog. You would think enough jogging would improve your stamina.